# How to draw a geom_tile plot

Tags: r, image, dataframe, matrix, ggplot2

I want to create a plot that shows work schedules for each day. The data I have to work with looks something like this:

```
   dput(head (TiNiSWeek, 3))

structure(list(`04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `04:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `04:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `06:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `07:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `07:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `07:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `07:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `08:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `08:15` = c(0, 
0, 2), `08:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `08:45` = c(0, 0, 2), `09:00` = c(0, 
2, 2), `09:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `09:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `09:45` = c(0, 
2, 2), `10:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `10:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `10:30` = c(0, 
2, 2), `10:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `11:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `11:15` = c(0, 
2, 2), `11:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `11:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `12:00` = c(0, 
2, 0), `12:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `12:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `12:45` = c(0, 
2, 2), `13:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `13:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `13:30` = c(0, 
2, 2), `13:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `14:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `14:15` = c(0, 
2, 2), `14:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `14:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `15:00` = c(0, 
2, 2), `15:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `15:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `15:45` = c(0, 
2, 2), `16:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `16:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `16:30` = c(0, 
2, 2), `16:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `17:00` = c(0, 2, 0), `17:15` = c(0, 
2, 0), `17:30` = c(0, 2, 0), `17:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `18:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `19:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `19:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `19:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `20:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `21:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `22:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `22:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `00:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `01:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `01:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `03:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `04:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `04:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `06:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `07:00` = c(2, 0, 0), `07:15` = c(2, 0, 0), `07:30` = c(2, 
0, 0), `07:45` = c(2, 0, 0), `08:00` = c(2, 0, 2), `08:15` = c(2, 
0, 2), `08:30` = c(2, 0, 2), `08:45` = c(2, 0, 2), `09:00` = c(2, 
2, 2), `09:15` = c(2, 2, 2), `09:30` = c(2, 2, 2), `09:45` = c(2, 
2, 2), `10:00` = c(2, 2, 2), `10:15` = c(2, 2, 2), `10:30` = c(2, 
2, 2), `10:45` = c(2, 2, 2), `11:00` = c(2, 2, 2), `11:15` = c(2, 
2, 2), `11:30` = c(2, 2, 2), `11:45` = c(2, 2, 2), `12:00` = c(2, 
2, 0), `12:15` = c(2, 2, 0), `12:30` = c(2, 2, 2), `12:45` = c(2, 
2, 2), `13:00` = c(2, 2, 2), `13:15` = c(2, 2, 2), `13:30` = c(2, 
2, 2), `13:45` = c(2, 2, 2), `14:00` = c(2, 2, 2), `14:15` = c(2, 
2, 2), `14:30` = c(2, 2, 2), `14:45` = c(2, 2, 2), `15:00` = c(2, 
2, 2), `15:15` = c(2, 2, 2), `15:30` = c(2, 2, 2), `15:45` = c(2, 
2, 2), `16:00` = c(2, 2, 2), `16:15` = c(2, 2, 2), `16:30` = c(2, 
2, 2), `16:45` = c(2, 2, 2), `17:00` = c(2, 2, 2), `17:15` = c(0, 
2, 2), `17:30` = c(0, 2, 0), `17:45` = c(0, 2, 0), `18:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `18:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `19:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `19:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `19:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `20:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `21:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `22:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `22:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `00:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `01:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `01:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `03:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `04:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `04:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `06:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `07:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `07:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `07:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `07:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `08:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `08:15` = c(0, 
0, 2), `08:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `08:45` = c(0, 0, 2), `09:00` = c(0, 
0, 2), `09:15` = c(0, 0, 2), `09:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `09:45` = c(0, 
2, 2), `10:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `10:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `10:30` = c(0, 
2, 2), `10:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `11:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `11:15` = c(0, 
2, 2), `11:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `11:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `12:00` = c(0, 
2, 2), `12:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `12:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `12:45` = c(0, 
2, 2), `13:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `13:15` = c(0, 2, 0), `13:30` = c(0, 
2, 0), `13:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `14:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `14:15` = c(0, 
2, 2), `14:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `14:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `15:00` = c(0, 
2, 2), `15:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `15:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `15:45` = c(0, 
2, 2), `16:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `16:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `16:30` = c(0, 
2, 2), `16:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `17:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `17:15` = c(0, 
2, 0), `17:30` = c(0, 2, 0), `17:45` = c(0, 2, 0), `18:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `18:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `19:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `19:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `19:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `20:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `21:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `22:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `22:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `00:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `01:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `01:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `03:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `04:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `04:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `06:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `07:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `07:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `07:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `07:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `08:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `08:15` = c(0, 
0, 2), `08:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `08:45` = c(0, 0, 2), `09:00` = c(0, 
2, 2), `09:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `09:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `09:45` = c(0, 
2, 2), `10:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `10:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `10:30` = c(0, 
2, 2), `10:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `11:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `11:15` = c(0, 
2, 2), `11:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `11:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `12:00` = c(0, 
2, 2), `12:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `12:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `12:45` = c(0, 
2, 2), `13:00` = c(0, 2, 0), `13:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `13:30` = c(0, 
2, 2), `13:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `14:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `14:15` = c(0, 
2, 2), `14:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `14:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `15:00` = c(0, 
2, 2), `15:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `15:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `15:45` = c(0, 
2, 2), `16:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `16:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `16:30` = c(0, 
2, 2), `16:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `17:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `17:15` = c(0, 
2, 2), `17:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `17:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `18:00` = c(0, 
0, 2), `18:15` = c(0, 0, 2), `18:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `19:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `19:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `19:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `20:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `21:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `22:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `22:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `00:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `01:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `01:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `03:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `04:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `04:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `06:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `07:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `07:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `07:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `07:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `08:00` = c(0, 0, 2), `08:15` = c(0, 
0, 2), `08:30` = c(0, 0, 2), `08:45` = c(0, 0, 2), `09:00` = c(0, 
2, 2), `09:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `09:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `09:45` = c(0, 
2, 2), `10:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `10:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `10:30` = c(0, 
2, 2), `10:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `11:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `11:15` = c(0, 
2, 2), `11:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `11:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `12:00` = c(0, 
2, 2), `12:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `12:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `12:45` = c(0, 
2, 2), `13:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `13:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `13:30` = c(0, 
2, 2), `13:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `14:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `14:15` = c(0, 
2, 0), `14:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `14:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `15:00` = c(0, 
2, 2), `15:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `15:30` = c(0, 2, 2), `15:45` = c(0, 
2, 2), `16:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `16:15` = c(0, 2, 2), `16:30` = c(0, 
2, 2), `16:45` = c(0, 2, 2), `17:00` = c(0, 2, 2), `17:15` = c(0, 
2, 0), `17:30` = c(0, 2, 0), `17:45` = c(0, 2, 0), `18:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `18:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `19:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `19:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `19:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `20:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `21:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `22:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `22:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `00:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `01:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `01:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `03:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `04:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `04:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `06:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `07:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `07:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `07:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `07:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `08:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `08:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `08:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `08:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `09:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `09:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `09:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `09:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `10:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `10:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `10:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `10:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `11:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `11:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `11:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `11:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `12:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `12:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `12:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `12:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `13:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `13:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `13:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `13:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `14:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `14:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `14:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `14:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `15:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `15:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `15:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `15:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `16:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `16:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `16:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `16:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `17:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `17:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `17:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `17:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `18:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `19:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `19:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `19:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `20:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `21:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `22:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `22:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `00:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `01:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `01:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `03:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `04:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `04:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `04:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `04:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `05:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `05:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `06:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `06:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `07:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `07:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `07:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `07:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `08:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `08:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `08:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `08:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `09:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `09:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `09:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `09:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `10:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `10:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `10:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `10:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `11:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `11:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `11:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `11:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `12:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `12:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `12:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `12:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `13:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `13:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `13:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `13:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `14:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `14:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `14:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `14:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `15:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `15:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `15:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `15:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `16:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `16:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `16:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `16:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `17:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `17:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `17:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `17:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `18:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `18:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `19:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `19:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `19:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `19:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `20:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `20:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `21:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `21:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `22:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `22:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `22:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `22:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `23:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `23:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `00:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `00:45` = c(0, 
0, 0), `01:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `01:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `01:30` = c(0, 
0, 0), `01:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:00` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:15` = c(0, 
0, 0), `02:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `02:45` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:00` = c(0, 
0, 0), `03:15` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:30` = c(0, 0, 0), `03:45` = c(0, 
0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Each line in the df represents a time step  (start time 04:00, end time 03:45, measured in 14 minutes) and there are seven days staring with Monday.

I would like to create a heatmap-type of plot using geom_tile (or geom_raster or geom_rect).

I would like to modify the x axis (to add breaks) as well the y axis (to replace with identification number).

Unfortunately, the data that I'm using doesn't seem to work, I think. I've tried to create a plot using all three geoms but without much success.

This is the only plot that I managed to create.

[image: Matrix image]

How can change this plot to represent the daily profiles profiles?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Trying to understand your data. The column labels are the times (clearly), the days are only distinguished as the the times repeat (e.g., if I said *the `\`06:30\`` column*, neither you nor R would be able to tell *which* column on *which* day I mean). What do the rows mean? You show 3 rows, what do they mean? All the values are either 0 or 2, what do they mean?

Comment: @Gregor thank you for your time. The 0 means did not worked and 2 means worked.

Comment: What do the different rows mean? Are there three different workers? When I see `08:30 = c(0, 0, 2)`, do you want that to look different than `14:30 = c(0, 2, 2)`? How so - do you want different plots for the first, second, and third rows? Or one plot, but the color is based on the average of the rows? Something else?

Comment: @Gregor the columns are time steps and the rows are serial numbers. One row will show a person weekely workschedule. As you can see on the yellow blue plot there are 60 cases. Thanks

Comment: @Gregor  the c(0, 0, 2)  at a specific time step (at the same time) means Monday did not worked, Tuesday did not worked and Wednesday worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using some wrangling to convert from matrix to data frame, and converting time character strings into "decimal hour since 4am."

```
TiNiSWeek %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  gather(time, val, -rowid) %>% 
  mutate(day = rep(weekdays, each = 96*3) %>% fct_relevel(weekdays),
         time_hm = hm(str_sub(time, end = 5)),
         time_dec_from_start = hour(time_hm) + minute(time_hm)/60 - 4) %>%       
  ggplot(aes(time_dec_from_start, rowid, fill = val)) +
  geom_tile() +
  facet_wrap(~day)
```

[image]

Comment: It probably makes sense here to change `time_dec_from_start` to include a modulo by 24 to move the negative values into the range [20-23.75], since they occur later than the other values, not before. But I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...